# What are the various ways of creating OpenGl ES graphics on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, sprite, mesh

I have done some reading on OpenGl ES for Android. I know that I could make a game with the canvas API, but I would like to experiment with OpenGl ES first.

From here I can see two options: Use a game engine or develop my OpenGl ES from the ground up.

The coder/math person that I am is pushing me to the harder option(second option). The way I want to start on this journey is by creating a mesh and manipulating it with various transformations. I will worry about the textures later on. I've learned that I could develop my mesh using outside software such as Blender or LibGdx. However, I would like to learn to develop it with the android API. Do you think this is possible? Will it be very taxing for the android system to process many meshes and transform them? I think It will.

Should I just stick to the game engine way, and forget the "from the ground up mindset".

I also just found out about the replica island source code. Perhaps, I should start reading it and tweaking it on my own.

One more thing, from what I see, I have several options when developing graphics on android using OpenGl ES. Create the 3D model meshes or use sprites(such as replica island). Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the complexity of the game.
If it's on the simpler side, you could very well 'start from scratch'. I'm pretty sure, you'll end up creating something similar to `replica island`. For a complex game, you'll be near (as we're from moon) `unity` on the other extreme. We're talking about hundreds of thousands of man-hours.

As far as `creating the meshes` is concerned, `OpenGL(ES)` can only render the meshes.

Unless it's a very primitive mesh or one which can be modelled mathematically with a few equations (less likely for a game), you'll have to create them in blender, maya etc.

For a first timer, I suggest reusing an existing game/engine.
The transition from rendering meshes, then applying textures, then using lighting and shadows etc has a decent learning curve.

Trust me, even with this approach the coder/Math person will have enough on his plate.

Comment: thanks for the advice Sahil Bajaj. I think I will learn Blender and import the mesh objects from there. I guess I could start with LibgDx, since there is support for meshes there.